# view on top of tableview dissapears

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview, tableview

I have a problem with my tableview. My first problem is that I have a tableview with a view on top. In this view there are 3 buttons. I am building this using story board.

[image]

My problem with this is that what I scroll down, my view disappears. How can I set this that this view always stays on top? At the moment you can see this view as the 'first cell'.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the view hierarchy on the left hand side you'll see that your header view is a subview of the table, so it scrolls with it.

From that hierarchy view drag it out of the table view so that it's at the same level.

Also, resize your table so that it starts underneath the view with the header bar.

Tim

Comment: When I try to do that my UIView always replacing my UITableview.

Comment: You need to drag `UIView` to the very top of your `UITableView` or as suggested move it in left window so it will become sibling of `UITableView`

Comment: @TomaszZabłocki my view is a sibling of UITableview?

Comment: Then just move down `UITableView' in Size Inspector tab or change size of UIView and UITableView accordingly so they will be located next to each other instead both having the same size.

Answer (score 0):

What if you select your view in Interface Builder, then go to `Editor->Arrange->Send to front`?